# SPRING, API, POST body request

Tags: spring, api

```
@PostMapping("/api/email/sendVerificationEmail/{email}")
    private boolean sendMail(HttpServletRequest request, @Pathvariable String email) {
        int randomCode = new Random().nextInt(10000) + 1000;
        String joinCode = String.valueOf(randomCode);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("joinCode", joinCode);

        String subject = "email verification";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("number is").append(joinCode).append(".");
        return mailService.send(subject, sb.toString(), "", email);
```

I'm using Spring and used to get request as @Pathvariable but I'd like to change to get request in body. Such as

```
{
"email": "aaaaaa@gmail.com"
}
```

How should I change it?

Comment: Hey @juststarted. Maybe provide what you have tried already.

Comment: Hi. I don't want to use @Pathvariable I want to send request in the body..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add @RequestBody annotation.

**Solution 1: Using the DTO**

```
@PostMapping("/api/email/sendVerificationEmail/")
private boolean sendMail(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody EmailDetails email){
    System.out.println(email.getEmail());
    return true;
}
```

Create a class:

```
class EmailDetails{
private String email;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

**Solution 2: Using Map**

If you have simple requirement with one or two fields then you can also go with Map as like:

```
 @PostMapping("/api/email/sendVerificationEmail/")
private boolean sendMail(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody Map<String,String> email){
    System.out.println(email.get("email"));
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dedicated DTO and @RequestBody, for exmaple

```
class YourDto{
    String email;
   + getters/setters
}
```

and then

```
  @PostMapping("/api/email/sendVerificationEmail")
  private boolean sendMail(@RequestBody YourDto dto){
     dto.getEmali();// well, it works!
  }
```